# n-torsion elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How does one show that the elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ annhilated by $n$ can be represented by $\lbrace \ [0], [1/n],[2/n], \ldots , [(n-1)/n]  \ \rbrace \subset \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: As with many small exercises, the answer should be clear once you have the meaning of everything in your head. What is an element of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$? What does it mean to be annihilated by $n$? It means blah, which in turn means blah, which is equivalent to yadda yadda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $E: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{C^\times}$ given by $E(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$. Then $E$ is a group homomorphism and $\ker E = \mathbb{Z}$. So, we have an injective map $\bar E: \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{C^\times}$. The image of $E$ and (of $\bar E$) is the set of roots of unit. The elements of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ annhilated by $n$ correspond under $\bar E$ to the set of $n$-th roots of unit, which is $\{  e^{2\pi i k/n} : k=0,1,\dots, n-1 \}$. The result you seek follows at once.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Any element of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique representative in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0, 1)$. That is, every element of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is of the form $[x] = x + \mathbb{Z}$ for some $x \in [0, 1)$. Now suppose $[x]$ is annihilated by $n$, then $n[x] = [0]$ (i.e. $nx + \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$). What can you deduce about $nx$, and hence $x$ (keeping in mind that $x \in [0, 1)$)?

Comment: just thinking loud. if $n[x]=[0]$ ,means $nx=m$ for some integer $m$. which means $x=\frac{m}{n}$, now $m = nq + r$ ,where $r<n$ or $r=0$,then $x=(nq+r)/n$,then $[x]=[r/n]$,and all possible such values of $[r/n]$ are $\lbrace [r/n] \  \vert  \ r \ \in  \lbrace0,1,\ldots,n-1 \rbrace \rbrace$

Comment: That's correct, but you can make things a bit simpler by using $x \in [0, 1)$ so $nx \in [0, n)$ and therefore $m = 0, 1, \dots, n - 1$.